# using datepicker from toolkit for windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have just downloaded this sample with source code: https://github.com/MicrosoftArchive/SilverlightToolkit - works just fine.

How can i add a `DatePicker`from the toolkit to my project?

Please be explicit, thank you!